# C#, Custom Color Palette

Tags: c#, colorbox

I have to create a color palette something similar to http://www.certapro.com/certapro-fad-palette-paint-colors.aspx. A custom color palette with different RGB combinations. What is the easiest way to do it? [Do I need to insert  picture box for each and every custom color Or else is there anyway to make the visual studio color dialog looks like this?)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1484/NET-Color-Picker-Controls

Answer (score 0):

The ColourDialogue.CustomColours property is an array of ints that defines the custom colours displayed by the dialog. The easiest way is to define a hard-coded array of ints. If you know the web-hex values of these colours you can use hexadecimal notation like so:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog MyDialog = new ColorDialog();
// Allows the user to select or edit a custom color.
MyDialog.AllowFullOpen = true ;
// Assigns an array of custom colors to the CustomColors property
// Note that the most significant byte is the alpha value,
// so most of the time it will remain FF
MyDialog.CustomColors = new int[]{ 0xFF974724, 0xFFe7eae3 };
```

If you don't know the hexadecimal values of the colours, I suggest equipping your browser with the EyeDropper add on that allows picking colours from webpages (or the equivalent for any non-chrome browsers).